# I have a problem in python for split part of a text with the line end charater of the sentences

Tags: python, regex, annotations

I want to analyse a xml files and one part of my program split the data into sentences but my line end characters are gone … I need them to add annotation with xml tag at the beginning and at the end of my sentences.

For now i have :

```
import re

line_end_chars = "!", "?", ".",">"


regexPattern = '|'.join(map(re.escape, line_end_chars))

line_list = re.split(regexPattern, texte)
```

### problem

if i run this code with the texte

```
" Je pense que cela est compliqué de coder. Où puis-je apprendre?"
```

that's gonna give me  :

```
["Je pense que cela est compliqué de coder",
"Où puis-je apprendre"]
```

and not what i'm looking for , which is :

```
["Je pense que cela est compliqué de coder.",
"Où puis-je apprendre?"]
```

And after that I could do a `.replace`  code to add my xml tag.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is using `re.sub` instead of `re.split` and then `str.splitlines()`:

```
import re

line_end_chars = "!", "?", ".",">"
s = "Je pense que cela est compliqué de coder. Où puis-je apprendre?"

print( re.sub('(' + '|'.join(re.escape(ch) for ch in line_end_chars) + ')\s*', r'\1\n', s).splitlines() )
```

Prints:

```
['Je pense que cela est compliqué de coder.', 'Où puis-je apprendre?']
```

Comment: Thank'sfor your help  , that's working well!!! 
Now i can finish my program with more efficacity .

Answer (score 0):

Two ways I can think of doing this.

```
import re

# Method 1)
line_end_chars = "!", "?", ".", ">"
regexPattern = '|'.join(map(re.escape, line_end_chars))
s = "Je pense que cela est compliqué de coder. Où puis-je apprendre?"
linelist = []

for substr, delim in zip(re.split(regexPattern, s), re.findall(regexPattern, s)):
    linelist.append(substr+delim)

# Method 2)
line_end_chars = ["!", "?", ".", ">"]
s = "Je pense que cela est compliqué de coder. Où puis-je apprendre?"
linelist = []

temp_str = ""
for c in s:
    if c in line_end_chars:
        linelist.append(temp_str+c)
        temp_str = ""
    else:
        temp_str += c
```

Both print

```
['Je pense que cela est compliqué de coder.', 'Où puis-je apprendre?']
```

Comment: Thank's you too , i tried yours methods and they are great too!   I save all the methods for learning .